# 20.04 login loop after update - startx not working

Tags: nvidia, login, xorg, 20.04

I'm experiencing a login loop after updating (automatic updater) this morning and the suggested solutions I found don't help. Meaning:

- Auto login is disabled in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`
- Permissions of `.Xauthority` is `-rw------- username username`
- Owner of `/tmp` is `root root` and permissions are `drwxrwxrwt`

I noticed the xserver isn't starting when I try from the console. I can't show the whole log file because it apparently "looks like spam" (this drives me crazy) so here's the last part:

```
[    57.686] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    57.686] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    57.686] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    57.687] xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
[    57.811] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for pci:0000:01:00.0: -19
[    57.811] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    57.811] (II) modeset(1): using default device
[    57.811] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    57.811] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    57.812] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    57.812] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    57.812]    compiled for 1.20.8, module version = 0.0.2
[    57.812]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
[    57.812] (EE) open /dev/fb0: Permission denied
[    57.812] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    57.812] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    57.812] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    57.812] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    57.812] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    57.812]    compiled for 1.20.8, module version = 0.0.2
[    57.812]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.1
[    57.812] (EE) open /dev/fb0: Permission denied
[    57.812] (II) modeset(G0): using drv /dev/dri/card0
[    57.812] (WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support
[    57.812] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    57.812] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    57.812] (EE) Screen 1 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    57.812] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    57.812] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[    57.812] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[    57.812] (EE) Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs        for all framebuffer devices

[    57.836] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Any hints what could be wrong? I'm a bit desperate and should start to work with this station again, I'd be very grateful for any help.

Kind regards.

Comment: Have you a ```xorg.conf``` file in ```/etc/X11/``` directory? Try creating one via running ```Xorg -configure``` in the console,then copy the ```xorg.conf``` in the current directory to ```/etc/X11```, then try ```startx``` again.

Comment: There's some progress now: There was no xorg.conf. `Xorg -configure` terminated with an error but still generated xorg.conf.new. Copied it to /etc/X11/xorg.conf and the xserver starts now but asks "Are you sure you want to proceed" on startup and looks ugly (green stripes, letters missing).

Comment: Looks like a problem with the configuration of the graphic card... When starting, at the menu, press 'e' to temporary edit the grub. Look for a line that starts with 'linux' (a line that somewhere says 'quiet splash'. Just at the end add 'nomodeset' (no quoting marks).

Comment: Rebooting helped to get rid of the missing letters and changing to another background picture and back solved the stripes. The "Are you sure you want to proceed" persists. I can live with this, I guess. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

xorg.conf was missing after update. Running `Xorg -configure` creates `xorg.conf.new` in the working directory. Copying it to the /etc/X11/ folder with `cp xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf` and restarting the x-server solves the problem.